# Service Discovery with Envoy

Tags: microservices, istio, envoyproxy

How does it work with Envoy?

Let's say I have configured an upstream cluster like this:

```
  clusters:
    - 
      name: "service_a_cluster"
      connect_timeout: "0.25s"
      type: "strict_dns"
      lb_policy: "ROUND_ROBIN"
      hosts:
        - 
          socket_address: 
            address: "service_a"
            port_value: 8786
```

How is my Envoy instance (ClusterManager?) going to resolve `service_a`?
To whom is it going to send DNS queries?

Answer (score 3):

Envoy has internal mechanisms for doing resolution, and these are all available through configuration.  It looks like you're using Envoy v2 apis, so the relevant high level config is in the [cluster object here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.17.0/api-v2/api/v2/cluster.proto#cluster).

If you read that, you'll notice the `hosts` field references the `type` field.  This `type` field tells envoy how to handle discovery/resolution.  The full details of that mechanism is [here](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.17.0/intro/arch_overview/upstream/service_discovery#arch-overview-service-discovery-types).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've checked it, but no examples, very terse, merely mentioning the DNS policies. Do you have any examples?

Comment: Oh sure; the values you can use are just the capitalized string literals of those values: `STATIC`, `STRICT_DNS`, `LOGICAL_DNS`, `EDS` or `ORIGINAL_DST` [another link](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.17.0/api-v2/api/v2/cluster.proto#envoy-api-enum-cluster-discoverytype)

Comment: What I meant to ask is how to resolve DNS queries? To whom to talk to?   _Strict DNS
When using strict DNS service discovery, Envoy will continuously and asynchronously **resolve the specified DNS targets**. Each returned IP address in the DNS result will be considered an explicit host in the upstream cluster. This means that if **the query returns three IP addresses**, Envoy will assume the cluster has three hosts, and all three should be load balanced to._  The docs say nothing about how.